# Arduino problems with reading and writing to serialport

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a program, which will read the data from usb port that arduino will send to me and display it. However, I get an error:

const port = new SerialPort('COM6', { baudRate: 9600 });
^
TypeError: SerialPort is not a constructor
Thanks

Node.js:

````
import Readline from '@serialport/parser-readline';
const port = new SerialPort('COM6', { baudRate: 9600 });
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '' }));
// Read the port data
port.on("open", () => {
  console.log('serial port open');
});
port.write("1", (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
    }
    console.log('message written');
  });
parser.on('data', data =>{
  console.log('State of light:', data);
});```
Arduino:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char command = Serial.read();
        if (command == "1") {
            Serial.println("1");
        } else if (command == '0') {
            Serial.println("0");
        }
    }
  delay(5000);
}
````

Answer (score 0):

You are not importimg SerialPort anywhere on your JS.

Add

```
import { SerialPort } from 'serialport'
```

At beginning of your file. If you didn't installed the package yet, you will need to run

```
npm install serialport
```

Otherwise you will get a missing module error.